# How to get a specific text in web scraping in r?

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape a website and map the artists to the url.

The element I am trying to pull from is here:

```
<title data-ng-bind="'Chartmetric | ' + $state.current.data.pageTitle" class="ng-binding">Chartmetric | Fleetwood Mac</title>
```

I would like to get the "Fleetwood Mac" out of the code.

the following code gives me the top part "                                      data-ng-bind
"'Chartmetric | ' + $state.current.data.pageTitle" "

Edit: will accept any answer that gives me the artist title

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
url = "https://app.chartmetric.com/artist?id=100"
parsed_page <- url %>% GET(., timeout(10)) %>% read_html

parsed_page%>% 
     html_nodes(":contains('Chartmetric')") %>%
     html_attrs()%>%
     unlist
```

Comment: Looks like login based so minimum you need to provide either authentication/cookies

Comment: @QHarr the logins don't work because there is an API service for this site... however I should be able to get get in with the cookies as I do have premium account just not an API account.  What would the cookies function look like?

Answer (score 2):

After you have provided rvest cookies or authentication, you should be able to extract the text with `html_text2()` from `rvest` package. After that you'd probably need string manipulation.

```
url %>% read_html %>% 
  html_nodes(":contains('Chartmetric')") %>% 
  .[2] %>% # Accessing the second node
  html_text2() # Extract the text
```

Comment: Thanks, the issue with this site is the JSON loads the data later, so it cant be scraped